# Xamarin : How to deactivate the need for user approval when installing an app

Tags: android, xamarin

We are building a Xamarin application for Android TV, our app (.apk file) can be downloaded from a remote server and then  installed (this is to apply new version to the device!)

The issue is that after downloading the .APK file, the OS asks the user if he accept to install the app! what we want is to deactivate this ask and allow direct installation after the download,

Is there any option at the OS level or code that can deactivate the need for user approval when installing an app?

Thanks!

Comment: If the apk is not coming from an pre-whitelisted source  (Google Play, Tencent, Samsung Store, etc...) within the OEM's modified version of the ASOP code, the OS will prompt the user, no way around it as it is a user security feature (otherwise apps could install 100s of other 3rd-party app without the user's consent/knowledge)

Comment: this has nothing to do with Xamarin - installation of the apk is entirely an Android OS issue

Comment: Sorry to say, but this is how every operating system made in the last 10 years works, it shouldn't be surprising.